# configure nsscache with samba4 active directory

Tags: active-directory, cache, samba4, nss

I have a problem caching the users from samba4 AD with nsscache, since there is no `uid`, rather `samAccountName` or `cn` in AD. When I use the uid-like attribute:

```
# Default uid-like attribute
ldap_uidattr = 'sAMAccountName'
```

I get the following error:

```
# nsscache  update --full
WARNING:root:invalid object passed: 'uid' not in {'modifyTimeStamp': ['20190915102717.0Z'], 'sAMAccountName': ['user'], 'cn': ['user']}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/nsscache", line 33, in <module>
    return_value = nsscache_app.Run(sys.argv[1:], os.environ)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nss_cache/app.py", line 240, in Run
    retval = command_callable().Run(conf=conf, args=args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nss_cache/command.py", line 230, in Run
    force_lock=options.force_lock)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nss_cache/command.py", line 303, in UpdateMaps
    force_write=force_write)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nss_cache/update/updater.py", line 275, in UpdateFromSource
    force_write, location=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nss_cache/update/map_updater.py", line 75, in UpdateCacheFromSource
    location=location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nss_cache/sources/source.py", line 63, in GetMap
    return self.GetPasswdMap(since)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nss_cache/sources/ldapsource.py", line 371, in GetPasswdMap
    since=since)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nss_cache/sources/ldapsource.py", line 589, in GetUpdates
    raise ValueError('Invalid object passed: %r', obj)
ValueError: ('Invalid object passed: %r', {'modifyTimeStamp': ['20190915102717.0Z'], 'sAMAccountName': ['user'], 'cn': ['user']})
```

Ist possible to configure nsscache with active directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is not possible to configure nsscache with active directory. After looking in to the source code, [here](https://github.com/google/nsscache/blob/master/nss_cache/sources/ldapsource.py#L585) is the exception I get and [here](https://github.com/google/nsscache/blob/master/nss_cache/sources/ldapsource.py#L620) are the essential fields needed as attributes of an object.

Neither `uid` nor `uidNumber` nor `gitNumber` are part of an object in samba4 active directory.

The `uid` attribute can be added, but neither `uidNumber` nor `gidNumber` are allowed according to the schema.